# mysql-proxy. Bad handshake

Tags: mysql, proxy

При подключении к БД через mysql-proxy появляется ошибка "Bad handshake". Причина не понятна, прошу знающих помочь в решении проблемы.

**Исходные данные:**

Сервер Debian 8. На нем установлен MySQL 5.7 и MySQL-Proxy.
mysql-proxy запускаю вручную (для возможности проверки)

```
mysql-proxy --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/mysql-proxy.cnf
```

```
[mysql-proxy]
log-level=message
log-file=/var/log/mysql-proxy.log

admin-username=admin
admin-password=admin
admin-address=127.0.0.1:4041
admin-lua-script=/usr/lib/mysql-proxy/lua/admin.lua

proxy-address=127.0.0.1:4040
proxy-backend-addresses=127.0.0.1:3306
proxy-lua-script=/etc/mysql/mysql-proxy.lua
```

```
sysop@proxy:~$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 4040 -uadmin -padmin
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

ERROR 1043 (08S01): Bad handshake

sysop@proxy:~$
```

В логах mysql точно такое же сообщение.

MySQL: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.29, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Данная ошибка появляется только при подключении через прокси. Напрямую к mysql подключение проходит.

пробовал добавить в настройки сервера директиву `skip-character-set-client-handshake`.

Comment: Похоже, что прокси использует неправильную клиентскую библиотеку для подключения к MySQL

Comment: Как это можно проверить? И указать ему на правильную библиотеку?